# Python text based game indentation

Tags: python

My Indentation problems start at line 40 inn my code. If someone could tell me how to fix it i would be very thankful

```
print "You wake up in a dark room, There is a box of matches in your pocket. What do you do?"
print "#1 Light a match #2 Do nothing"
door = raw_input(">")
if door == "1":
    print "You light a match, In the room there is an axe and a door without a handle. What do you do?"
    print "#1 Grab the axe #2 Punch the door #3 Do nothing"
    axe = raw_input(">")
    if axe == "1":
        print "You grab the axe, What do you do?"
        print "#1 Knock down the door #2 Do nothing"
        end = raw_input(">")
        if end == "1":
            print "You are free! You Win!"
        elif end == "2":
            print"You wait and then the axe slips out of your hand, decapacitating you. You die"
        else:
            print "Ivalid input. Game End"   
    elif axe == "2":
        print"Ow, that hurt. What to do now?"
        print "#1 Grab the axe #2 do nothing"
        chop = raw_input(">")
        if chop  == "1":
            print" You grab the axe, What do you do?"
            print "#1 Knock down the door #2 Do nothing"
            end = raw_input(">")
            if end == "1":
                print "You are free! You Win!"
            elif end == "2":
                print"You wait and then the axe slips out of your hand, decapacitating you. You die"      
            else:
                print "Ivalid input. Game End"    
        elif chop == "2":
            print "You go insane from waiting. Game Over"     
        else:
            print "Ivalid input. Game End"       
    elif axe == "3":
        print "You go insane from waiting. Game Over"    
    else:
        print "Ivalid input. Game End"  
elif door == "2":
    print"You wait in the darkness until something grabs your arm. Whate do you do?"
    print"#1 Use your ninja skills to escape the clutches of whatever is grabbing you. #2 Flail your arms around"
    flail = raw_input('>')
    if flail == "1":
        print"You escape from the things grasp. What do you do now?"
        print"#Light a match. #2 Throw a punch at the whatever was attacking you"
        punch = raw_input('>')
        if punch == "1":
            print"You light a match only to see a hideous monster in front of you. What do you do now"
            print"#1 Throw the match at the monster #2 Punch the monster"
            match = raw_input('>')
            if match == "1":
                print"You throw a match at the monster. The monster eats the match then turns dissapears. What do you do"
                print"#1 Panic #2 Look around"
                panic = raw_input('>')
                if panic == "1":
                    print"You panic then have a heart attack. You die. Game over"
                elif panic == "2":
                    print"You look around, it appears the monster is gone.In the room there is an axe and a door without a handle. What do you do?"
                    print "#1 Grab the axe #2 Punch the door #3 Do nothing"
                    axe = raw_input(">")
                    if axe == "1":
                        print "You grab the axe, What do you do?"
                        print "#1 Knock down the door #2 Do nothing"
                        end = raw_input(">")
                        if end == "1":
                            print "You are free! You Win!"
                        elif end == "2":
                            print"You wait and then the axe slips out of your hand, decapacitating you. You die"
                        else:
                            print "Ivalid input. Game End"   
                    elif axe == "2":
                        print"Ow, that hurt. What to do now?"
                        print "#1 Grab the axe #2 do nothing"
                        chop = raw_input(">")
                        if chop  == "1":
                            print" You grab the axe, What do you do?"
                            print "#1 Knock down the door #2 Do nothing"
                            end = raw_input(">")
                            if end == "1":
                                print "You are free! You Win!"
                            elif end == "2":
                                print"You wait and then the axe slips out of your hand, decapacitating you. You die"      
                            else:
                                print "Ivalid input. Game End"    
                        elif chop == "2":
                            print "You go insane from waiting. Game Over"     
                        else:
                            print "Ivalid input. Game End"       
                    elif axe == "3":
                        print "You go insane from waiting. Game Over"    
                    else:
                        print "Ivalid input. Game End"      
                else:
                    print"Invalid Input. Game end"
            else:
                print"Invalid Input. Game end"        
        elif match == "2":
            print"You punch the hideous monster in its face and it dies. You look around and you see a axe and a door without a handle. What do you do?"
            print "#1 Grab the axe #2 Punch the door #3 Do nothing"
            axe = raw_input(">")
            if axe == "1":
                print "You grab the axe, What do you do?"
                print "#1 Knock down the door #2 Do nothing"
                end = raw_input(">")
                if end == "1":
                    print "You are free! You Win!"
                elif end == "2":
                    print"You wait and then the axe slips out of your hand, decapacitating you. You die"
                else:
                    print "Ivalid input. Game End"   
            elif axe == "2":
                print"Ow, that hurt. What to do now?"
                print "#1 Grab the axe #2 do nothing"
                chop = raw_input(">")
                if chop  == "1":
                    print" You grab the axe, What do you do?"
                    print "#1 Knock down the door #2 Do nothing"
                    end = raw_input(">")
                    if end == "1":
                        print "You are free! You Win!"
                    elif end == "2":
                        print"You wait and then the axe slips out of your hand, decapacitating you. You die"      
                    else:
                        print "Ivalid input. Game End"    
                elif chop == "2":
                    print "You go insane from waiting. Game Over"     
                    else:
                        print "Ivalid input. Game End"       
            elif axe == "3":
                print "You go insane from waiting. Game Over"    
            else:
                print "Ivalid input. Game End"      
        else:
            print"Invalid Input. Game end"        
    else:
        print"Invalid Input. Game end"        
elif punch == "2":
    print"The monster eats your hand whole and you bleed to death. Game Over"
        else:
            print"Invalid Input. Game end"
    elif flail == "2":
        print"You flail your arms and then you get killed by the mmonster. Nice job. You lose. Game Over"
    else:
        print"Invalid input. Game end."
else:
    print"Invalid Input. Game end."
```

Comment: Please reformat your post in code format, and post the exact error message that you received. Until then, it is more or less impossible to give you a solution.

Comment: @JakobBowyer "The thing you're doing? You're doing it badly. You should do it better." That's what you just told him. How is that constructive at all? If you have a SPECIFIC way he can better implement this, you should write it as an answer (as I did when I recommended a finite state machine)

Comment: Indicating which line is line 40 might be a good start...

Answer (score 4):

I see it I see it!

```
elif punch == "2": # you can't `elif punch` here, because you haven't defined punch (maybe)
    print"The monster eats your hand whole and you bleed to death. Game Over"
        else: # else what? there's nothing here to "else!"
            print"Invalid Input. Game end"
```

Note that this kind of a game is best implemented using a ["finite state machine"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), which may be a bit beyond your abilities at the moment. Just wanted to mention it since you currently have spaghetti code, and I don't want you to think that "This is how code Should Look," it shouldn't. There is, however, no better way to do it at your current knowledge level :)

Comment: You're right on, but you messed up the formatting a bit. the print is correctly indented it's the else that is bad.

Comment: @DeadChex actually I missed an indent on everything. It's fixed now :)

Comment: Good, just wanted to make sure the indents didn't bite you too

Answer (score -1):

```
print "You wake up in a dark room, There is a box of matches in your pocket. What do you do?"
print "#1 Light a match #2 Do nothing"
door = raw_input(">")
if door == "1":
    print "You light a match, In the room there is an axe and a door without a handle. What do you do?"
    print "#1 Grab the axe #2 Punch the door #3 Do nothing"
    axe = raw_input(">")
    if axe == "1":
        print "You grab the axe, What do you do?"
        print "#1 Knock down the door #2 Do nothing"
        end = raw_input(">")
        if end == "1":
            print "You are free! You Win!"
        elif end == "2":
            print"You wait and then the axe slips out of your hand, decapacitating you. You die"
        else:
            print "Ivalid input. Game End"   
    elif axe == "2":
        print"Ow, that hurt. What to do now?"
        print "#1 Grab the axe #2 do nothing"
        chop = raw_input(">")
        if chop  == "1":
            print" You grab the axe, What do you do?"
            print "#1 Knock down the door #2 Do nothing"
            end = raw_input(">")
            if end == "1":
                print "You are free! You Win!"
            elif end == "2":
                print"You wait and then the axe slips out of your hand, decapacitating you. You die"      
            else:
                print "Ivalid input. Game End"    
        elif chop == "2":
            print "You go insane from waiting. Game Over"     
        else:
            print "Ivalid input. Game End"       
    elif axe == "3":
        print "You go insane from waiting. Game Over"    
    else:
        print "Ivalid input. Game End"  
elif door == "2":
    print"You wait in the darkness until something grabs your arm. Whate do you do?"
    print"#1 Use your ninja skills to escape the clutches of whatever is grabbing you. #2 Flail your arms around"
    flail = raw_input('>')
    if flail == "1":
        print"You escape from the things grasp. What do you do now?"
        print"#Light a match. #2 Throw a punch at the whatever was attacking you"
        punch = raw_input('>')
        if punch == "1":
            print"You light a match only to see a hideous monster in front of you. What do you do now"
            print"#1 Throw the match at the monster #2 Punch the monster"
            match = raw_input('>')
            if match == "1":
                print"You throw a match at the monster. The monster eats the match then turns dissapears. What do you do"
                print"#1 Panic #2 Look around"
                panic = raw_input('>')
                if panic == "1":
                    print"You panic then have a heart attack. You die. Game over"
                elif panic == "2":
                    print"You look around, it appears the monster is gone.In the room there is an axe and a door without a handle. What do you do?"
                    print "#1 Grab the axe #2 Punch the door #3 Do nothing"
                    axe = raw_input(">")
                    if axe == "1":
                        print "You grab the axe, What do you do?"
                        print "#1 Knock down the door #2 Do nothing"
                        end = raw_input(">")
                        if end == "1":
                            print "You are free! You Win!"
                        elif end == "2":
                            print"You wait and then the axe slips out of your hand, decapacitating you. You die"
                        else:
                            print "Ivalid input. Game End"   
                    elif axe == "2":
                        print"Ow, that hurt. What to do now?"
                        print "#1 Grab the axe #2 do nothing"
                        chop = raw_input(">")
                        if chop  == "1":
                            print" You grab the axe, What do you do?"
                            print "#1 Knock down the door #2 Do nothing"
                            end = raw_input(">")
                            if end == "1":
                                print "You are free! You Win!"
                            elif end == "2":
                                print"You wait and then the axe slips out of your hand, decapacitating you. You die"      
                            else:
                                print "Ivalid input. Game End"    
                        elif chop == "2":
                            print "You go insane from waiting. Game Over"     
                        else:
                            print "Ivalid input. Game End"       
                    elif axe == "3":
                        print "You go insane from waiting. Game Over"    
                    else:
                        print "Ivalid input. Game End"      
                else:
                    print"Invalid Input. Game end"
            else:
                print"Invalid Input. Game end"        
        elif match == "2":
            print"You punch the hideous monster in its face and it dies. You look around and you see a axe and a door without a handle. What do you do?"
            print "#1 Grab the axe #2 Punch the door #3 Do nothing"
            axe = raw_input(">")
            if axe == "1":
                print "You grab the axe, What do you do?"
                print "#1 Knock down the door #2 Do nothing"
                end = raw_input(">")
                if end == "1":
                    print "You are free! You Win!"
                elif end == "2":
                    print"You wait and then the axe slips out of your hand, decapacitating you. You die"
                else:
                    print "Ivalid input. Game End"   
            elif axe == "2":
                print"Ow, that hurt. What to do now?"
                print "#1 Grab the axe #2 do nothing"
                chop = raw_input(">")
                if chop  == "1":
                    print" You grab the axe, What do you do?"
                    print "#1 Knock down the door #2 Do nothing"
                    end = raw_input(">")
                    if end == "1":
                        print "You are free! You Win!"
                    elif end == "2":
                        print"You wait and then the axe slips out of your hand, decapacitating you. You die"      
                    else:
                        print "Ivalid input. Game End"    
                elif chop == "2":
                    print "You go insane from waiting. Game Over"     
                    else:
                        print "Ivalid input. Game End"       
            elif axe == "3":
                print "You go insane from waiting. Game Over"    
            else:
                print "Ivalid input. Game End"      
        else:
            print"Invalid Input. Game end"        
    else:
        print"Invalid Input. Game end"        
elif punch == "2":
    print"The monster eats your hand whole and you bleed to death. Game Over"
        else:
            print"Invalid Input. Game end"
    elif flail == "2":
        print"You flail your arms and then you get killed by the mmonster. Nice job. You lose. Game Over"
    else:
        print"Invalid input. Game end."
else:
    print"Invalid Input. Game end."
```

needs parentheses for new versions of python

Comment: You'd better format your code, if you want someone to read it.